# 'JavaScriptCode' action failed with error code 'UnknownError'

Tags: azure-logic-apps

This inline JavaScript step just started failing. I haven't touched it in days. It's been running perfectly until now. How can I trouble-shoot:

```
InternalServerError. The 'JavaScriptCode' action failed with error code 'UnknownError'.
```

?

[image: 'JavaScriptCode' action failed with error code 'UnknownError']

Answer (score 0):

> "InternalServerError: The 'JavaScriptCode' action failed with error code 'UnknownError'"

This error could be because of multiple reasons, and in your case, this might be happening because of change in environment or configuration.

Check if my below findings help you to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Check if your JavaScript code has any syntax errors or unexpected values.
2. Check the developer tools for any exceptions in the code.
3. Check if there is any missing dependency.
4. Check if the configuration includes the instrumentation key as a string value.

If the issue still exists, you can raise a bug/ticket on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues) with the code and clear details.